# In react-native we use styleSheet.create. What do we use in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In react-native we use styleSheet.create. What do we use in reactjs?

Thanks for the help!

https://github.com/romseguy/redux-store-visualizer

I dont see any use of style here but there is styling. how did he achieve this or did i miss out anything?

Comment: There is no need for a special call to styleSheet.create because CSS is supported natively on the web. Just pass the raw styles object to the style attribute and it will inline them. You could also just use a regular old stylesheet and classes

Comment: https://github.com/romseguy/redux-store-visualizer/blob/master/index.js#L8

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The analogous option would be to do something like the following:

```
let styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}
```

Like one of the comments stated above, the StyleSheet call is unecessary because CSS is supported already on the browser.

Finally, just call the style inline in your render function's return statement:

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    <div style={styles.container} />
  )
}
```

Of course, aside from that, you have a few other options as well, like using plain CSS stylesheets and classes/tags, but this is probably the most similar option to what you're used to.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using TypeScript in your project you could define StyleSheet like this:

```
interface StyleSheet {
  [key: string]: React.CSSProperties;
}
```

And then create styles very similar as with StyleSheet.create from RN.

```
const styles: StyleSheet = {
  navStyle: {
    listStyleType: 'none',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%'
  },
  anotherStyle: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a TypeScript implementation of StyleSheet.create({}) from React Native to React.

```
import React from "react";

type CSSProperties = {
  [key:string]: React.CSSProperties;
};

export class StyleSheet {
  static create<Styles extends CSSProperties>(styles: Styles): Styles {
    return styles;
  };
};
```

**usage:**

create an object which contains React's CSS properties:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",

    height: "100vh",
  },

  loadingContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  loadingText: {
    color: "#dcdcdc",

    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    fontWeight: 500,
  },
});
```

now you know what properties that object has when use it in your Reactjs components:

[take a look at a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyGS0.png)

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Mitacho/fd7049db3dad80d9500851d81ce3153f

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline style property like:

```
<div style={{ background: 'red' }}>
```

Or simply plain css / scss.

There is also [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) you could look into.

---

Regarding you edit,

In the [DevTools.js](https://github.com/romseguy/redux-store-visualizer/blob/master/containers/DevTools.js#L12-L17), you can see some inline style that gets passed as props to the `<ChartMonitor />`.

There is some `className` definitions like [here](https://github.com/romseguy/redux-store-visualizer/blob/master/components/Footer.js#L17) that will aloow you to change the style in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. [Inline Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style)
2. [CSS Stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/#article-header-id-4)
3. [CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-2-getting-started/)

There is an excellent [Styling React Components](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-styling-components/table-of-contents)' course on Pluralsight that covers all of these options

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, but there is an easy npm package that does exactly what you ask for.
Check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-stylesheet
Just use it like you would do in react native:

```
import Stylesheet from "reactjs-stylesheet";
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
    myStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#81D4FA",
        color: "#263238",
        width: "100px",
    },
});
```